# Максимальный размер кэша в AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, кэширование

Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста, какой максимально допустимый объем данных я могу поместить в кэш в AngularJS используя `$cacheFactory`?

Comment: А какой максимально допустимый размер данных Вы можете поместить в обычный объект javascript?

Comment: Не знаю, пробовал гуглить, ничего толкового не нашел.

Comment: Я к тому, что просто нужно экономно использовать ресурсы браузера. Вы можете внести в этот объект столько информации, что хватит на несколько библиотек, но это скажется на производительности, в конечном итоге. Используйте инструменты разработчика, чтобы эмпирическим путем определить максимально допустимый размер, без вреда производительности всей аппликации.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если говорить о количестве записей, так оно устанавливается параметром `capacity`.
[Из исходников](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/cacheFactory.js#L3):

```
capacity = (options && options.capacity) || Number.MAX_VALUE
```

Где Number.MAX_VALUE = 1.7976931348623157e+308
Остальное ограниченно характеристиками клиента, разрядностью, но как правильно замечают в комментариях никому не захочется испытывать предельные значения размеров кэша. Скорее всего вы можете писать туда разумные количества информации.